# How to update multiple models on mongoose and return updated models as an array?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

this is my code, the ids arg is an array of ids of models i wanted the status field set to true:

```
async function seenAllNotification(ids) {
  return await Notification.update({ _id: { $in: ids }}, { status: true }, { multi: true });
}
```

would this work? i also wanted it to return the models as an array of objects, I also tried this, which doesn't work:

```
async function seenAllNotification(ids) {
  const notifs = await Notification.update({ _id: { $in: ids }}, { seen: true })
  if (notifs) {
    const allNotifs = await Notification.find({ '_id': { $in: ids } });
    return allNotifs;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Details on few things**

1.`Notification.update` returns this json object `{ n: 4, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`

- `n` is number of targeted rows
- `nModified` is number of modified rows
- `ok` is update success/error

2.A method prefixed with `async`  will return a promise. This method could be invoked using `.then` callback

**Below is the code** using `async` `await`

```
var seenAllNotification = async ()=>{
    var find = null;
    var update = await Notification.update({_id : ids},{ status: true },{ multi: true });
    //{ n: 4, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
    if(update.n == ids.length){
        find = await Notification.find({_id : ids});
        return {find,update};
    }
    else{
        throw new Error("some ids are not updated")
    }
};
```

Notice that i have returned both find and update object using a json object.

`return {find,update}` will be automatically translated into `return {find:find, update:update}`

Returning `find,update` could be useful if its necessary to send any of these details in response object for rendering.

```
seenAllNotification().then((response)=>{
   console.log("updated elements ",response.find);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("err ",err);
})
```